# Directory Permissions CentOS

Tags: permissions, centos

The scenario I'm trying to achive is the following:
1 directory created by root and give access to a group of people.

Therefore i create a group called 'testgroup' and a new user 'testuser' that belongs to 'testgroup'.
I gave permissions rwx to owner and rw to group and none to the others.

But the testuser cannot go inside this directory. What i'm doing wrong ?

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      4096 Sep 12 21:02 .
drwx--x--x 46 root root      4096 Sep 12 21:02 ..
drwxrw----  6 root testgroup 4096 Sep 12 21:02 test
-bash-4.1$ cd test
-bash: cd: test: Permission denied
-bash-4.1$ id
uid=32010(testuser) gid=32015(testgroup) groups=32015(testgroup)
-bash-4.1$
```

Also i tried relloging - but still couldnt have access to that directory.
If i give him execute permissions he can change to that directory. But i dont want to allow him executing scripts, just read/write. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the execute bit on your 'test' directory for the 'testgroup' group

`chmod 770 test` (rwx for owner, rwx for group, no access for everyone)

A directory must have the execute bit set in order to access the files within.

When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission
   bits have different meanings than on regular files.

- The write bit allows the affected user to create, rename, or delete
  files within the directory, and modify the directory's attributes
- The read bit allows the affected user to list the files within the
  directory
- The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and
  access files and directories inside